# Prove $R/(1+i)$ is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> $R=\{a+bi|a,b\in \mathbb{Z}\}$, Prove $R/(1+i)$ is a field.

I can write the element of $R/(1+i)$  exactly. Actually $R/(1+i)=\{\bar{0},\bar{1}\}$. And I can examine every condition that make a set to be a field. But I think this makes it a little inelegant. What's the more effective ways.

Comment: Show that $(1+i)$ is a maximal ideal - which follows from the fact that there are less than four cosets. Btw, are you aware that $(1-i)(1+i)=2$?

Comment: Taking a field modulo a nonzero field element leads you nowhere.

Comment: You overcounted the elements of $R/(1+i)$.  We have $-1=1$ in $R/(1+i)$.  Note that $1-(-1)=2=(1-i)(1+i)=0$ as an element of $R/(1+i)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$
R/(1+i) \cong \mathbb Z[x]/(x^2+1,1+x) = \mathbb Z[x]/(1+x,2) \cong \mathbb Z/(2)  \cong \mathbb F_2
$$
Indeed, $2=(x^2+1)+(1+x)(1-x)$ implies
$$
(x^2+1,1+x)
=(x^2+1,1+x,2)
=(x^2-1,1+x,2)
=(1+x,2)
$$